# Perform multiple Kruskal tests in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, kruskal-wallis

I want to perform a `kruskal_test` for multiple variables. I have been able to do this with anova tests as follows:

```
vars = c("Sepal.Length" , "Sepal.Width" ,"Petal.Length" ,  "Petal.Width")

for (i in vars) {
  
  f <- reformulate(paste(i,'~Species'))
  test = aov(data = iris, f )
  
  print(i)
  print(summary(test))
```

But I can't seem to use the same method for `rstatix::kruskal_test` or `kruskal.test`:

```
for (i in vars) {
  
  f <- reformulate(paste(i,'~Species'))
  test = kruskal.test(data = iris,formula= f )
  test = kruskal_test(data = iris,formula= f )
  print(i)
  print(summary(test))
  
}
```

I get errors:
Error in kruskal.test.default(data = iris, formula = f) :
argument "x" is missing, with no default

or

Error in kruskal.test.formula(formula, data = data, ...) :
'formula' missing or incorrect

Comment: You don’t need an explicit `for` loop, in R you can run them all using `lapply(iris[vars], function(x) kruskal.test(Species ~ x, data = iris))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `aov` you need this kind of formula,

```
> reformulate(paste('Petal.Width','~Species'))
~(Petal.Width ~ Species)
```

whereas in `kruskal.test`, it's

```
> reformulate('Petal.Width', 'Species')
Species ~ Petal.Width
```

The generic function appears to have an unexpected issue in its method dispatch mechanism, indicating a possible bug in its method selection process (R 4.3.2). Even though the arguments are named, the order matters (default order is `kruskal.test(formula, data)`, we have `kruskal.test(data, formula)`):

```
> kruskal.test(formula=Petal.Width ~ Species, data=iris)

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  Petal.Width by Species
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 131.19, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

However:

```
> kruskal.test(data=iris, formula=Petal.Width ~ Species)
Error in kruskal.test.default(data = iris, formula = Petal.Width ~ Species) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

It works if you use the method directly

```
> for (i in vars) {
+   f <- reformulate(i, 'Species')
+   test <- stats:::kruskal.test.formula(data=iris, formula=f)
+   print(test)
+ }

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  Species by Sepal.Length
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 107.29, df = 34, p-value = 1.596e-09


    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  Species by Sepal.Width
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 47.879, df = 22, p-value = 0.001125
...
```

Better use **`lapply`** though:

```
> lapply(vars, \(v) stats:::kruskal.test.formula(data=iris, formula=reformulate(v, 'Species')))
[[1]]

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  Species by Sepal.Length
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 107.29, df = 34, p-value = 1.596e-09


[[2]]

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  Species by Sepal.Width
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 47.879, df = 22, p-value = 0.001125
...
```